# Resources$NotFoundException on android after updating to NativeScript 5

Tags: android, nativescript

I am unable to updates the project to NativeScript 5, it's giving the folowwing error on android

```
System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6
System.err:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2155)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1180)
System.err:     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:137)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1073)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1554)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

tns doctor says
No issues were detected.

```
√ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
√ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
√ The Android SDK is installed.
√ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
√ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
√ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
√ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 5.0.1 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-core-modules has 5.0.3 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-android has 5.0.0 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-ios has 5.0.0 version and is up to date.
```

P.S. I have upgraded the CLI first as mentioned [this github issue](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/914)